Can I use OR condition with Relationships in Tableau
I have 2 tables in tableau & I want to create a many to many relationship between them based on an OR condition between fields. So I basically want either the account name or the parent account name to match in both tables. Is there a way of doing that?
The data sources have different data so it doesn't make sense to join them using SQL as they are unrelated, only common factor is the account & parent names.

You can use custom sql in your tableau data source to create a join with an arbitrary join condition.

You can use custom SQL in your tableau data source to create a join with any boolean join condition that you like, so yes there is a way to use Tableau to view such a relationship - as long as you don't mind writing a dash of SQL.
The relationships and joins that you specify in the Tableau user interface only implement the common case of an AND applied to each clause in the condition, where each clause compares two values - each value drawn from one (but only one) of the two tables being joined. That supports well the vast majority of use cases where relationships are based on basic equi-join conditions.
Custom SQL is useful in situations like this where you want to use a database specific SQL function, a windowing query, or an unusual join condition. But use it sparingly -- that is, don't make your whole data source one giant SELECT statement. Use Tableau relationships between tables and views as much as possible. That allows Tableau to be more flexible and performant about the SQL it generates, and simplifies the work you have to do to make use of Tableau -- e.g. much less need for complex LOD calculations among other simplifications.
